# Error while importing euclidean_distances from sklearn.metrics.pairwise

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, anaconda

I am trying to import euclidean_distances from python shell
with following syntax

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
```

and I got following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
>     File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics__init__.py", line 7, in 
>       from .ranking import auc
>     File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\ranking.py", line 26, in 
>       from ..utils import check_consistent_length
>     File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils__init__.py", line 16, in 
>       from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight
>     File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\class_weight.py", line 7, in 
>       from ..utils.fixes import in1d
>     File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 318, in 
>       from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr
>     File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg__init__.py", line 109, in 
>       from .isolve import *
>     File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve__init__.py", line 6, in 
>       from .iterative import *
>     File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py", line 7, in 
>       from . import _iterative
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I have installed scikit-learn modules and also I can locate euclidean_distances method in `sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py`

Comment: What you tried worked for me with Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit) that I installed on 8/11/15.  Suggest reinstalling scipy or the latest Anaconda Python 2 distro.